# How can i duplicate rows in excel and copy value from one cell to another?

Tags: vba, excel

How can i duplicate rows 3 or 4 times in excel using VBA or using conditional statements, and then copy and paste values from one cell to another.

This is how the data looks like

[image]

and this how i would like to end up to.

[image]

Update: on the code below I want to copy merge in to row,  col no 176, 177,178, 179, 180 it works great but remove all columns  between the 1  col and 176 col.

```
Sub SortMacro()
 Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
 Dim OutSheet As Worksheet

Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
Set OutSheet = Sheets.Add

With SourceSheet
Out_i = 1
 For r = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 176).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 176 To 180     'or For each i in Array(3,4,5)
        OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 1) = .Cells(r, 1)
        OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 176) = .Cells(r, i)
        Out_i = Out_i + 1
    Next
 Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Change __OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 176) = .Cells(r, i)__ to __OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 2) = .Cells(r, i)__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open VBA edior (Alt-F11). Create new VBA module (rightclik to VBA Project, insert, module). Copy this code to the new modul. Run the code (select sheet with source data, then click anywhere into the VBA code-text and press F5).

```
Sub SortMacro()
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim OutSheet As Worksheet

Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
Set OutSheet = Sheets.Add

With SourceSheet
    Out_i = 1
    For r = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 3 To 5     'or For each i in Array(3,4,5) 
            OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 1) = .Cells(r, 1)
            OutSheet.Cells(Out_i, 2) = .Cells(r, i)
            Out_i = Out_i + 1
        Next
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!, almost there but i have around 20 columns i want to separate only three columns for example Col G, K, L and i want keep everything the same.

Comment: The inner loop loops through the columns. You can change it to _For each i in Array(3,5,6,8,9)_ to get any columns you want.

Comment: I want to merge cols starting 176-180 it works fine but it deletes or doesn't show all the content of the cell on the columns between the 1st and Col 176

Answer (score 0):

`MyRange.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset).Value = MyRange.Value`